# Celery / Django - How to programatically see workers' states

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, amazon-sqs

I just installed Celery and I want to create a simple status page that shows the current number of workers and their status.

Is this possible?  From web searches the best I found was `celery.current_app.control.inspect()`

But as far as I can see, it doesn't mention anything about workers.  (I'm using Kombu with SQS for the backend if that matters)

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/mher/flower? Even official Celery docs recommend it (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html?highlight=flower#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor).

Comment: Flower looks nice, but for my porpoises I need to plug this into an internal system health check.  So I need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Then you need to extend flower.

Comment: or check it's source code and try to figure out how it works

Answer (score 7):

In [the documentation of celery workers](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=inspect#inspecting-workers) it is explained the output of the `inspect` commands.

By default using `celery.current_app.control.inspect()` returns an "inspector object" that allows you to ask for the state of all the running workers. For example if you execute this code with two running workers named 'adder' and 'sleeper':

```
    i = celery.current_app.control.inspect()
    i.registered()
```

the call to `i.registered()` could return something like:

```
    {
      'adder@example.com': ['tasks.add'],
      'sleeper@example.com': ['tasks.sleeptask'],
    }
```

In conclusion, the "inspector" methods `registered`, `active`, `scheduled`, etc. return a dictionary with the results classified by the workers chosen when `celery.current_app.control.inspect()` was called (if no workers are passed as arguments, all workers are implicitly selected).

Comment: That looks promising.  It's strange though, when I call that I get an SQS authentication error.  Even though my app and workers can connect fine.  Maybe this call requires an extra permission on the SQS queue?

Comment: Here's that error: SQSError: SQSError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access to the resource https://queue.amazonaws.com/ is denied.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>37b59c-ee-aa5c-faeb0ecba29f</RequestId></ErrorResponse>

Comment: It seems that it may not be supported yet: [SQS does not yet support worker remote control commands](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html#caveats).

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if that means flower won't work either.

Comment: Celery seems to use the same `inspect` API and also the `events` API (which is not supported for SQS either) to update the state of its workers, so I guess it won't work either.

Comment: This Celery issue states that the `celery inspect` command is unavailable for SQS brokers: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6727

Comment: To update @MarcoA. 's 2016 comment on this question, the new documentation that they linked can be found here: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html#:~:text=SQS%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20yet%20support%20worker%20remote%20control%20commands.